# GWT ui.xml conversion

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, gwt

```
<select><option value="AND">AND</option><option value="OR">OR</option></select>
```

How to convert this HTML code to ui.XML?

Comment: `textList = textList.stream().map(s -> "%" + s).collect(Collectors.toList());` for your other question. BUT, it creates a new List object and uses a loop both behind the scenes, breaking your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate it to widgets using [ListBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html):

```
<g:ListBox>
  <g:item value='AND'>AND</g:item>
  <g:item value='OR'>OR</g:item>
</g:ListBox>
```

Or keep it as elements using [HTMLPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html):

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <select>
    <option value="AND">AND</option>
    <option value="OR">OR</option>
  </select>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```